# Attach a custom view to spyne

Tags: python, spyne

I am using Spyne to provide SOAP interface to my backend, but a need one or more custom views accessible on certain URLS. For example to show some statistics in HTML.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the multiple protocols example here: https://github.com/arskom/spyne/tree/master/examples/multiple_protocols

If you want to return raw data via Http, you must set your output protocol to `HttpRpc`, your output type in your service to `ByteArray` or `String` and `ctx.transport.mime_type` to whatever type you're returning

Comment: Looks like this won't work without `werkzeug` :( Additional dependency for me. Anyway thank you for the response.

Comment: werkzeug is needed only for url routing, which is only used in ``DynProtService``. Other examples don't need werkzeug at all.